# Copy page builder layout

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Can someone help me how to copy layouts of page builder(i. e html content) from one page to another in enterprise edition magento2. 3, is there a way to do

Comment: I guess it is frontend page builder. rt?

Comment: Its magento2. 3 ee page builder, yes it is frontend page builder

Comment: I think you are talking about the content it generates in pages of wysisyg editor rt?

Answer (score 0):

Frontend page builder generally has some specific syntax that it adds to the wysiwyg editor for all the pages. 
When you add or remove any content from front-end it basically adds or deletes the particular codes inside the cms pages in order to efficiently manage the dynamic content from the front-end itself without any prior knowledge of coding.

But the problem is when you try to copy the content from the page, default enabled wysiwyg editor don't let you copy the same exact code that the front-end builder has generated so far.

In order to copy the content, you first need to disable the wysisyg editor and then it will be same as page-builder has generated

Go to **Store > Configuration > General > Content Management**

And inside WYSIWYG Options tab, go to Enable WYSIWYG Editor option and set it to **Disabled by default**. You may need to uncheck use system value checkbox to do so. After that, click save and close.

Now when you try to copy from content from page, it will be same as generated by front-end builder.

Though you may need to understand it's syntax for which code is generated for which blocks and so on.

Comment: But after this , he still will not be able to edit page by page builder on same level like was before but from scratch?

Comment: I guess there is already some theme over there. So try to reinstall the theme in another fresh Magento installation and copy code from there for a particular page.

And if it is just static HTML, then you can even copy-paste from theme demo(normally provided if it is purchased from sites like ThemeForest) from the inspect element in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to copy the HTML generated by Page Builder from the Magento app. You'll need to access your database and find the associated entity and retrieve the HTML code via that method.

The master format is self contained and transferable (minus assets like images) so you'll be able to save and restore this as you please.

You can read more about our master (storage) format here: https://devdocs.magento.com/page-builder/docs/reference/architecture.html#storage-format